# Stop touch event during touch move

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

In my game, when time is up, I want to display another view and stop the interaction on the others currently used before the time stopped.
But when the other view is coming, if I let my finger on the screen, I can stil drag into the view behind the new view and continue the game.... That's not the purpose.

I want to lose the focus of the finger, or cancel the finger...
I tried to set userInteraction to NO.. but not working.

Can somebody knows how to solve this issue?

The quickFix is to setup a shared variable and test it in the touchBegan and TouchMoved event.. but that's not proper :)

Thank a lot!

Comment: Hi,
it's not working.
Apparently when you touch the screen on a view, if another view is coming above it, the finger stays on the view behind. 
I want to loose focus on a view during the tracking.
With a shared value, it's possible.. but the proper solution??

Answer (score 0):

Your -touchesMoved:withEvent: method can check whether the timer is still running before it does anything. If the timer expires, it stops changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

1.Ignore the events while animation.

2.Instead of setting userInteraction to NO ignore the events.

Use these methods to ignore events

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```